# How to make input type=file Should accept only pfx file

Tags: html, forms

I used

Now I would like to restrict this by accepting only .pfx files.

I have tried accept=".pfx" but it's not working.

Could anyone please give some examples for this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"not working"_? Works just fine here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/7yn29zes/

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="file" accept=".pfx">
```

It will only work on browsers that support the accept attribute. Some older browsers may not honor the attribute, and the user may still be able to select files of any type.
You have to make it on the back-end side(server-side) to make a validation for accept only ".pfx" files